# mysql: Key reference and table reference don't match

Tags: sql, mysql, associations, shopware

The error information:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1239 Incorrect foreign key definition for 'fk.faq.product_id': Key reference and table reference don't match
```

product table:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
    `id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `version_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME(3) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`version_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

faq table:

```
CREATE TABLE `faq` (
    `id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `question` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `answer` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `product_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME(3) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fk.faq.product_id` (`product_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk.faq.product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`,`version_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I made a faq table to combine with the product table, but it comes always error and I can't find what is wrong with my table? thanks for help.

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Your FK has only one column but it is referencing a PK that has 2 columns

Comment: I have tried to delete the `version_id` by references and used only id for product, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Im not sure what your last comment means. The Product PK is id + version; an FK on one table must refer to a PK (or unique key) on another table; so the FK on the faq table must reference the PK on Product and therefore you need both a product Id and a version column on the faq table and include them both in your FK definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove comma at the end of this - PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`version_id`) , remove not null from `product_id` BINARY(16) ,  remove version_id from REFERENCES `product` (`id`,`version_id`)

https://dbfiddle.uk/rg25idw-

and read

'in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order'

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html